# Jewish Khan Academy

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, internet

Does anyone know if there is something similar to the [khan academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/) for limudei kodesh?

I'm looking for something like [this](http://kmtt.libsyn.com/) just with the whiteboard aspect that khan academy uses.

Comment: [yutorah.org](http://www.yutorah.org)

Comment: divineinformation.com learntorah.com torahanytime.com aish.com chabad.org doresh-tzion.co.il rabimeir.com torahlectures.com KOLHALASHON.COM theshmuz.com puretorah.com torahohr.net and many more for Torah lectures, but I'm not sure if they are exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @ Hacham Gabriel I didn't check all the sites you posted, but I'm looking for something more like http://kmtt.libsyn.com/ with the whiteboard aspect that khan academy uses.

Comment: Let's make one!!

Comment: @Vram From the FAQ page on Khan Academy, it looks like you just need $280 and a youtube account. I think the extra money was for salaries/keeping the site running.

Comment: Please [edit] more information into the question about what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: i am working on it. collaborators are welcome to contact me at urischneider at gmail.com

Comment: Aleph Beta-- alephbeta.org. It's a pretty amazing website; R' Fohrman's content is very eye-opening.

Comment: torahcafe.com (Chabad-oriented but has a lot of other stuff too)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any site that covers entire "courses" of torah, but there are many sites that have large selections of torah videos, such as http://www.webyeshiva.org or http://koshertube.com.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.kolhalashon.com/New/HomePage/NewDefault.aspx?Lang=English&English=True
http://olamot.net/

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something that I think will answer what you are asking. I started a youtube channel that teaches in a khan academy style how to learn gemarah. I think that when the question comes up of whether or not we should have a jewish KA, the most important thing to realize is what KA actually is. Long torah lectures do not fit the style of what makes KA so effective.

For example, most of the topics on KA are skills that build on other topics and are short and encapsulated. (math and physics, are a bunch of concepts that all build up to a larger thing.)

Torah can never be replaced in toto by a bunch of video lectures since an integral part of studying torah is by having a rebbe.

That being said, the skills required to learn torah can be taught in a KA style. (I would think that an advanced degree of lumdus would require learning under a rebbe for many years though)

It's not a simple discussion. There are definitely parts of torah that can be made into a KA format, and I think will do really well; however, there are also many things that cannot be taught like that.

Those are some thoughts on the discussion. If you would like to check my channel out (mostly focused on gemarah reading skills) you can find it on youtube under the channel name Talmud Tutor

Comment: Talmud Tutor welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your first answer! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: Welcome Talmud Tutor. I suggest to change the range of the letter h to +1.

Answer (score 0):

[TorahLive](https://torahlive.com/) is a very interesting equivalent of Khan Academy in the Jewish world, producing  high-quality content with extensive video and computer effects.

Comment: @TzafnasPaneach the cost of production of an hour of Khan Academy is very low because they use very little technology. It is a doodle with a voice explaining the lecture. TorahLive takes a very different approach and produces very high end content with video and computer effects. As such the effect is much more wow visually but costs more to produce.